Why does my Kubernetes pod enter a CrashLoopBackOff state when using Liveness and Readiness Probes together?
I'm new to Kubernetes (K8S) and trying to learn how to achieve zero downtime during deployments. I have two services: currency-exchange and currency-conversion, where currency-conversion depends on currency-exchange.
When I deploy a new version of currency-exchange, the old pod stops immediately, causing an internal server error since the new pod isn't ready yet. To prevent this, I added Readiness and Liveness probes to the deployment YAML so that Kubernetes checks the pod's health before terminating the old one. My understanding is that this should help maintain zero downtime.
The Issue: When I add both the Liveness and Readiness probes, the new pod fails to start correctly and enters a CrashLoopBackOff state after multiple restarts.
this is my deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  labels:
    app: currency-exchange
  name: currency-exchange
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: currency-exchange
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: currency-exchange
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: username_24/currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: mmv2-currency-exchange-service
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 8000
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 8000
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
              memory: 2Gi
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: currency-exchange
  name: currency-exchange
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: currency-exchange
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer

this is the related props in the application.properties
## Activate the health probes (liveness and readiness) to avoid downtime
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true

What I've Tried: I tried removing the Liveness probe and using only the Readiness probe. This seems to work fine, and there is no downtime during deployment. However, I need to understand why the pod fails and enters CrashLoopBackOff when the Liveness probe is enabled.
Any insights into what might be going wrong or how to properly configure these probes to avoid downtime would be greatly appreciated!

Try adding initialDelaySeconds in readinessProbe and livenessProbe as explained in this blog and let me know if it works.

Two notes, if your app supports it, you should consider setting replicas to 2 (or more) and then set the upgrade strategy to "RollingUpdate". Also you can add a preStop hook in a deployment yaml to allow your pod to gracefully terminate so no running processes/connections terminate early. Simple example of a preStop could be a sleep 20

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?

Set initialDelaySeconds to allow your app to fully initialize before the first probe is run, seconds.Set periodSeconds to check the readiness probe.
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 8000
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 10

Set initialDelaySeconds to allow your app to fully initialize before the first probe is run,.Set periodSeconds to check the liveness probe. Set failureThreshold to allow for a couple of failed probes before restarting the container.
livenessProbe:
 httpGet:
 port: 8000
 path: /actuator/health/liveness
 initialDelaySeconds: 30
 periodSeconds: 20
 failureThreshold: 3

For more information refer to the  blog by Pierre and a blog by Adam and an official kubernetes document.

For more information check my answer in this stack link.
